# Rails: using eager_loading scope gives an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a `Rails` project, and trying to create a `scope` in my model instead of an `instance method` and `preload` that scope when needed. But I'm not very experienced with scopes and having trouble getting it to work or may be I'am doing it all wrong. I had an instance method doing the same thing, but noticing some n+1 issues with it. I was inspired by this article [How to preload Rails scopes](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-to-preload-rails-scopes/) and wanted to try scopes.

(As a side note, I'm using `ancestry` gem)

I have tried three different ways to create the scope. They all **works for** `Channel.find_by(name: "Travel").depth`, **but errors out for** `Channel.includes(:depth)` or `eager_load`.

**first try**:

`has_one :depth, -> { parent ? (parent.depth+1) : 0 }, class_name: "Channel"`

**2nd try**:

`has_one :depth, -> (node) {where("id: = ?", node).parent ? (node.parent.depth+1) : 0 }, class_name: "Channel"`

**3rd try**:

`has_one :depth, -> {where("id: = channels.id").parent ? (parent.depth+1) : 0 }, class_name: "Channel"`

All three works fine in console for:

```
Channel.find_by(name: "Travel").depth 
Channel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "channels".* FROM "channels" WHERE "channels"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Travel"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 2
```

**..but**

`Channel.includes(:depth)` gives me **three different errors** for each scope (1st, 2nd, 3rd);

Error for first scope:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `parent' for #<Channel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fdf867832d8>)
```

Error for 2nd scope:

```
ArgumentError (The association scope 'depth' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading instance dependent scopes is not supported.)
```

Error for 3rd scope:

```
Object doesn't support #inspect
```

What am I doing wrong? Or, what is the best approach? I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `.depth` method is returning an integer value not associated records. Eager loading is the mechanism for loading the associated records of the objects returned by `Model.find` using as few queries as possible.

If you want to speed the `depth` method you need to enable the `:cache_depth` option. According to ancestry gem documentation:

```
:cache_depth           
   Cache the depth of each node in the 'ancestry_depth' column(default: false)
   If you turn depth_caching on for an existing model:
   - Migrate: add_column [table], :ancestry_depth, :integer, :default => 0
   - Build cache: TreeNode.rebuild_depth_cache!
```

In your model:

```
class [Model] < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_ancestry, cache_depth: true
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Juan. I end up taking a different approach without using depth. But would like to try your answer.